# Need help to call data source in for_each

Tags: terraform

I am replacing count with for_each for following code. Need help in referring index of resource when calling data source of azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories under dynamic "log".

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "diag" {
  count                      = length(var.resource_id)
  name                       = "diag"
  target_resource_id         = var.resource_id[count.index]
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id

  dynamic "log" {
    for_each = data.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories.resource[count.index].logs
    content {
      category = log.value
      enabled  = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same information when finding your question.
The below works for me:

```
  dynamic "log" {
    for_each = [for lg in data.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories.webui.logs : {
      lg_name = lg
      }
    ]
    content {
      category = log.value.lg_name
      enabled  = true

      retention_policy {
        enabled = false
      }
    }
  }
```